# Ways to find where an object is contained in Java?

Tags: java, class, dependencies

I am having a class which is declared as.

```
public class StatusMessage {

    private Status status;
    private String message;
    private Throwable throwable;
    private List<StatusMessage> children;

    getters ; setters;
}
```

This enables me to have an endless tree like structure of StatusMessages by adding children.

Sample Code to add child.

```
StatusMessage parent =new StatusMessage(status,message);
parent.getChildren().add(new StatusMessage(status,message));
parent.getChildren().add(new StatusMessage(status,message));
parent.getChildren().add(new StatusMessage(status,message));
StatusMessage child1 =new StatusMessage(status,message);
parent.getChildren().add(child1);
StatusMessage child1_1 =new StatusMessage(status,message);
child1.getChildren().add(child1_1);
....
```

Is there any way i will be able to find out that child1 is the parent of child1_1 similarly travel from the lowest level to the root?

I want to achieve this by not adding a reference to parent in the child. Is there any way to do this in Java? Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, can only think of ways that would be horribly more complex than simply adding the parent.

Comment: If the children do not have a reference upward to the parent, I don't see any way to accomplish what you want.  Maybe if you can give an example of how you plan to traverse your `StatusMessage` tree it would help us to give you a better answer.

Comment: If a status message does not know its parent or the collection it was added to, how could you find out where it is? You must traverse it from the root: [List.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) is your friend. But for the requirement you posted, the easiest way would be to add a parent field.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, there is no way in Java to find objects that are referring to an object in question if there is no explicit reference held in a field.

If you have such a requirement, the easiest way is really to add a `parent` field to your class `StatusMessage`. But make sure to deal with it correctly:

1. Remove the getter for the internal `List` of children. No one outside of a status message should be allowed to manipulate that list. In fact, that list is an implementation detail.
2. Instead add a `addChild` or a `addToParent` method (or both) to your class. These methods have to handle the parent-child relationships correctly:

---

```
public void addChild(StatusMessage child) {
    if (child.parent != null) {
        child.parent.children.remove(child);
    }
    child.parent = this;
    children.add(child);
}
```

---

```
public void addToParent(StatusMessage parent) {
    if (this.parent != null) {
        this.parent.children.remove(this);
    }
    this.parent = parent;
    this.parent.children.add(this);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion. My concern was on maintaining consistency in maintaining reference between parent and child if i add a reference in the child object.

Your suggestion will be helpful to maintain that reference integrity since the list is not exposed outside for manipulation. 

Thankyou for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot find out which objects refer to a particular object.

You probably just want to add a `parent` field (and make sure to set it correctly).